# How to fake the "via iPhone" status message in Facebook

Tags: facebook, iphone

Not beeing economically able to actually buy the new iPhone, how can I impress my friends and family by posting status messages with the "via iPhone" postfix?

Comment: hey, why the downvote? Trying to understand the mechanism behind the "via" postfix in facebook status feeds. Dont downvote just because you dont know the answer!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suggest because you said that you want to impress friends and family by faking a status message. You could have just asked how to do it. Anyway: This will not be possible since it's internally added from the official Facebook for iPhone app.

Comment: Okay, thanks, just tried to add some humor. What do you mean by "internally added"?

Comment: Doesn't the the Touch still display iPhone, or have they finally changed it to be specific to the device? When I had my iPod Touch, it showed iPhone whenever I posted to Facebook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to create a Facebook application.  When you sign up for a new application using the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api), I think the name you give your application will be the name that shows up in the "via" part of the post.  I doubt you'll be able to register your application under the name **iPhone**, but you could maybe do one that is just as "cool".

See the [status.set](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/status.set) method on how to set the status using the API.  This requires some programming, but the API has libraries available for most programming languages.

Comment: Thank you - will look into it, maybe "iPhone4" would be allowable

Comment: There's a lot of info on the FB API page, but there are also a lot of tutorials on the web for using the FB API.   Hey - Why not use "iPhone5" - if you're going for cool - that will surely impress them!  That is until Apple or Facebook come after you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [PostedVia](http://www.postedvia.com)

> PostedVia is a simple, easy-to-use tool that lets you fake where your
>   Facebook status was posted from. You can choose from a huge variety of
>   these delivery methods including Carrier Pigeon, Magic, Morse Code,
>   and Mind Control. Surprise your friends and family with these funny
>   Facebook status updates!

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See my edit on how you should answer questions. Please also take some time to read our [FAQ] Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can use websites like e.g. http://fbstatusvia.com to post via almost anything